# sed whitespace match question

Tags: ubuntu, sed, regular-expression, tcsh

I have this file -

```
#
# gridID 1
#
gridtype  = lonlat
gridsize  = 10512
xsize     = 144
ysize     = 73
xname     = lon
xlongname = "longitude"
xunits    = "degrees_east"
yname     = lat
ylongname = "latitude"
yunits    = "degrees_north"
xfirst    = 0
xinc      = 2.5
yfirst    = 90
yinc      = -2.5
```

and I want to search and replace

```
xfirst  = 0
```

with

```
xfirst = -180
```

I tried this on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sed s/=[[:space:]]0/-180/
```

and I get

```
sed:No match
```

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: your expression `sed s/=[[:space:]]0/-180/ file` does not give me `sed:No match` but returns the output with line `xfirst    -180`

Comment: `sed` just doesn't substitute if there is no match. There is a `No match` error in GNU `sed`, but I'm not sure how it is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to quote the `[[:space:]]` glob operator and are using a shell like `csh`, `tcsh`, `fish` (though `fish` doesn't support `[...]` glob operators), `zsh`, `bash -O failglob` (most probably `(t)csh` given the error message) that (rightly) fails the command when a glob fails to match.

`tcsh` doesn't recognise the `[:space:]` POSIX character classes, but that `s/=[[:space:]]0/-180/` is still recognised as a glob.

After a `mkdir -p 's/=a]0/-180'`, the glob would match. That `s/=[[:space:]]0/-180/` would be expanded to `s/=a]0/-180/` and you wouldn't get the `No match` error.

Instead, here, you want to quote that for the shell not to consider it as a glob pattern and pass the string literally to `sed`.

(Here, I'm also adding the missing `*` to allow 0 or more spacing characters in the pattern, and the missing `=` in the replacement):

```
sed 's/=[[:space:]]*0/=-180/'
```

Or to preserve the original spacing:

```
sed 's/\(=[[:space:]]*\)0/\1-180/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ***sed*** expression:

```
sed 's/^\(xfirst[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\).*/\1-180/' file
```

---

- `\1` - points to the 1st captured group (i.e. `(xfirst....)`)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will try this out. Can you also explain where I went wrong ?

Comment: your expression will remove `=<space>` along with `0`

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` command approach.

```
sed '/^xfirst/ s/\d\+/-180/'
```

or this way.

```
sed '/^xfirst/ s/[0-9]+/-180/'
```

or simply replace `0` with `-180`

```
    sed '/^xfirst/ s/0/-180/'
```